# Error building the application iOS using QtCreator

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, qt, qt-creator

Good day.
I'm trying to use Qt to develop an application for iOS.
I using macOS Mojave 10.14.5 and xCode 10.2.1 (installing from the AppStore).
Qt Creator - version 4.7.2 & qt - version 5.11.2 (also i tryed use Qt Creator - version 4.9.1 & qt - version 5.12.3). I create simple application "Qt Widget", and trying build his. I get the only error:

```
error: [xcodebuild-debug-simulator] Error 64
```

I inspect my kits and virtual devices, but they configured correctly:
[image]
[image]

Also, I can start any virtual device and it loading successful:
[image]

Why appears this error? Thank.

P.S. sorry, possibly my English language not quite correctly.

P. S. S. :I install macOS on VMware Workstation 15.

**UPD1:**
I created simple app from Xcode, and app is running successful.

Comment: I'm curious whether you would get the same error if you replace the VMware virtual machine with a real macOS.

Comment: @user3405291 I make this and write the results

Comment: @user3405291 I update post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compile app in Qt Creator, but I run app from xcode, and app started successful. There were complaints about *Bundle version*
and *Bundle version string short*, I corrected them in the file Info.plist.